# How do I add an iframe to getElementById?

Tags: javascript

I would like to remove the image `logo.png` lines in the js below and replace with iframe code.

```
currentRoomId = document.getElementById('roomID').value;

if ( document.getElementById('room_' + currentRoomId + '_bg') ) {
    document.getElementById('login_banner').src = document.getElementById('room_' + currentRoomId + '_bg').value;
}
else if ( document.getElementById('login_banner').src != "http://somedomain.com/header/logo.png" ) {
    document.getElementById('login_banner').src = "http://somedomain.com/header/logo.png";
}

if ( document.getElementById('room_' + currentRoomId + '_bg_link') && document.getElementById('room_' + currentRoomId + '_bg_link').value != 'FREE' ) {
    document.getElementById('login_banner_link').href = document.getElementById('room_' + currentRoomId + '_bg_link').value;
}
else if ( document.getElementById('login_banner_link') ) {
```

I would like to switch this, which is inside the html:

```
<img src="http://somedomain.com/logo.png" id="login_banner" /></a>
```

to this:

```
<iframe class="animation" src="http://somedomain.com/header/index.html" id="login_banner"></iframe>
```

so the back end can recognize if it should show the default banner, or a client banner.

I would need to have the js code edited to reflect the final html output.

Thank you.

Comment: Just find the image whose id = `login_banner` and remove that.  Replace it with your iframe code.  Then you can simply remove the JavaScript code that manipulates the old login_banner image.

Comment: Please add some of the html code, especially the element that you want to add the iframe to. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question appropriately, in plain javascript, you can use this code to remove the image and insert a frame in its place:

```
// create frame element
var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
frame.className = "animation";
frame.id = "login_banner";
frame.src = "http://somedomain.com/header/index.html";

// insert frame before img
var img = document.getElementById('login_banner');
img.parentNode.insertBefore(frame, img);

// remove img
img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
```

If you're trying to do something different, please clarify your question.

---

I'm not sure exactly where you want to insert this code, but if you want it in the last`else if` in the code you posted, it would go like this:

```
currentRoomId = document.getElementById('roomID').value;

if ( document.getElementById('room_' + currentRoomId + '_bg') ) {
    document.getElementById('login_banner').src = document.getElementById('room_' + currentRoomId + '_bg').value;
}
else if ( document.getElementById('login_banner').src != "http://somedomain.com/header/logo.png" ) {
    document.getElementById('login_banner').src = "http://somedomain.com/header/logo.png";
}

if ( document.getElementById('room_' + currentRoomId + '_bg_link') && document.getElementById('room_' + currentRoomId + '_bg_link').value != 'FREE' ) {
    document.getElementById('login_banner_link').href = document.getElementById('room_' + currentRoomId + '_bg_link').value;
}
else if ( document.getElementById('login_banner_link') ) {
    // create frame element
    var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
    frame.className = "animation";
    frame.id = "login_banner";
    frame.src = "http://somedomain.com/header/index.html";

    // insert frame before img
    var img = document.getElementById('login_banner');
    img.parentNode.insertBefore(frame, img);

    // remove img
    img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
}
```

---

If all you want to do is to know what the HTML is for adding an iframe to your page, then it would be this:

```
<iframe class="animation" src="http://somedomain.com/header/index.html" id="login_banner" height="400" width="400"></iframe>
```

Comment: I edited my original post. I think what you entered is correct. I just want to make sure. Thank you.

Comment: I added one more thing to my answer a few minutes ago based on what you added so the frame would also have the login_banner id.

Comment: @Brandon - You put this code wherever it is that you want to replace the image with the iframe once the page has loaded.  I can't tell you what the iframe will look like as that depends upon the content in it.  Try it and see.  You probably need to set the height and width of the iframe too.

Comment: Look at my code example for putting an id on the iframe.  You can either specify width and height by setting the `.height` and `.width` properties of the iframe object or by setting a CSS style like `.style.height = "100px"` on it or by using a CSS rule.

Comment: @Brandon - I don't know if you remove that or not because I don't know what that test it for in your logic.

Comment: @Brandon - since you're new on StackOverflow, are you aware that if someone answers your question, you should click the green arrow to the left of that answer.  This indicates to the community that you've received an answer and it rewards the person providing the answer with reputation points and you earn some reputation points for following the proper procedure.  Reputation points earn you more advanced privileges on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Brandon - you add this code in with your script where you've detected that no keyword is present and you want the iframe to show instead.  I can't help with that logic because you haven't shared it, but presumably you'd have some sort of logic in pseudo code: `if (no keyword detected) {put this code here}`.

Comment: @Brandon - which if/else is where you want to insert the iframe?

Comment: @Brandon - The code I gave you replaces the image with the iframe in the exact same place the img was since that is what I thought you were asking for.  The code placement doesn't affect where the HTML goes.  The iframe is inserted where the image was.  I asked you which branch of your if/else code is the one where you detect that you want to replace the image.

Comment: @Brandon - I've done my best to understand what you want.  I've added the code to the last `else if` in the code you posted and added that to my answer.  I'm going offline shortly now.

Comment: @Brandon - I give up.  You asked how to replace an image with an iframe (which I gave you the exact code to do), not how to add new HTML to your page.  I have no idea what you're trying to do.  You haven't described a clear enough question and you haven't given us enough information to help.

Comment: OK, I added the iframe HTML to the end of my answer.  You have an extra `;` in what you proposed and you need a height and width like I've shown.